# Undistorting without calibration images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, camera, computer-vision

I'm currently trying to "undistort" fisheye imagery using OpenCV in C++. I know the exact lens and camera model, so I figured that I would be able to use this information to calculate some parameters and ultimately convert fisheye images to rectilinear images. However, all the tutorials I've found online encourage using auto-calibration with checkerboards. **Is there a way to calibrate the fisheye camera by just using camera + lens parameters and some math?** Or do I have to use the checkerboard calibration technique?

I am trying to avoid having to use the checkerboard calibration technique because I am just receiving some images to undistort, and it would be undesirable to have to ask for images of checkerboards if possible. The lens is assumed to retain a constant zoom/focal length for all images.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), before posting a question.

Comment: have a look at "Straight lines have to be straight
F Devernay, O Faugeras - Machine vision and applications, 2001 - Springer"

Comment: and "Thomas Stehle, Michael Hennes, Sebastian Gross, Alexander Behrens, Jonas Wulff, Til Aach
Dynamic Distortion Correction for Endoscopy Systems with Exchangeable Optics
In: Bildverarbeitung für die Medizin (BVM)"

Comment: maybe this one or its cited papers: https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.11386

Comment: what do you mean by "knowing the exact lens and camera model"?

Answer (score 1):

To un-distord an image, you need to know the intrinsic parameters of the camera which describe the distorsion.
You can't compute them from datasheet values, because they depend on how the lens is manufactured and two lenses of the same vendor & model might have different distorsion coefficients, especially if they are cheap one.

Some raster graphics editor embed a lens database from which you can query distorsion coefficients. But there is no magic, they built it by measuring the lens distorsion and eventually interpolate them after.

But you can still use an empiric method to correct at least barrel effect.
They are plenty of shaders to do so and you can always do your own maths to build a distorsion map.